# How can I add a StyledComponent as a property to a another StyledComponent in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components, mobile-development, react-typescript

[This is what I'm trying to do. It works just fine in JavaScript but not in TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAzbs.png)

```js
export const Container = styled.View`
    align-items: center;
`;

Container.Title = styled.Text`
    font-family: Poppins-Regular;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
`;
```

```js
Property 'Title' does not exist on type 'StyledComponent<typeof View, DefaultTheme, {}, never>'.
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in CodeSandbox? It is easier to see what you have done so far and help that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

```
To prevent TypeScript errors on the css prop on arbitrary elements, install
@types/styled-components and add the following import once in your project:

import {} from 'styled-components/cssprop'
```

So try running `npm install --save-dev @types/styled-components` and adding that import somewhere.

Source: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#usage-with-typescript

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I just had to change **import {} from 'styled-components/cssprop'** to **import * as types from 'styled-components/cssprop'** as module cssprop could not be found